# What is the difference between "Do I go?" and "Am I going?"

Tags: grammar

I have doubt of this difference. Please help me, what is the major difference is therebetween the two?

Comment: Where is your research? Try: present simple and present progressive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Do I go” is asking about a habitual action. “Do I go to the cinema?” is asking whether I sometimes go to the cinema. “Am I going” is asking about my current situation. “Am I going to the cinema” is asking whether I am currently in the process of going to the cinema.

There are other less likely possibilities, depending on context. “Do I go the cinema or stay at home?” is asking me to make a decision now between these two alternatives. “Am I going to go to the cinema” is asking if I will be going to the cinema at some time in the future.

Comment: Nice explanations thank you so much @Mike Scott